# Vue.js: como formatar um valor em um v-model?

Tags: vue.js

Estou com o seguinte problema, eu preciso formatar um valor de um input, diretamente quando o usuário vai preenchendo o campo (@keypress ou @input).

Quando eu utilizo o método para formatar fora do input ele funciona, porém se eu tentar utilizar com o v-model acredito que ele conflite os valores.

Qual seria uma alternativa para essa questão?

Esse é o método:

```
formatPrice(value) {
      let val = (value / 1).toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
      return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    }
```

Essa é a chamada:

```
    {{ formatPrice(valorPrecoImovel) }}
      <input class="ipt-precoimovel" type="text" v-model="valorPrecoImovel" v-on:keypress="isNumber($event); formatPrice;" id="precoImovel">
```

Eu não consigo chamar o método dentro do *v-model*, por exemplo:

```
v-model="formatPrice(valorPrecoImovel)"
```

Comment: Queres formatar o valor dentro do input ou só o que está no template dentro de `{{ }}`?

Comment: o valor dentro do input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que queres fazer tem alguma complexidade pois combinas o `v-model` com a formatação do valor do input que o utilizador está a inserir.

Podes fazer isso usando um valor *computed* **e** usando *setters* e *getters* para ter mais controlo sobre o seu valor. Combinando isso com uma variável/propriedade interna `meu_valor` podes fazer o que procuras.

Fica um aspeto por tratar (que creio estar fora do escopo da pergunta) que é o posicionamento do cursor quando se escreve.

Uma sugestão da primeira parte (que descreves na pergunta) seria:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    meu_valor: '0,00'
  },
  computed: {
    valorPrecoImovel: {
      // getter
      get: function() {
        return this.meu_valor;
      },
      // setter
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.meu_valor = this.formatPrice(newValue);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatPrice(value) {
      const val = Number(value.replace(",", "."));
      if (!val) return '0,00';
      const valueString = val.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
      return valueString.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input class="ipt-precoimovel" type="text" v-model="valorPrecoImovel" ref="precoImovel" id="precoImovel">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`v-model` é apenas para atribuição. Você não vai conseguir formatar os resultados da forma que você chamou `v-model="formatPrice(valorPrecoImovel)"` pois não se trata de uma expressão de atribuição.

O que eu sugiro para você é deixar o `v-model` livre para definir os valores e formatá-lo através de um callback em `@input`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  
  new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   data: {
       meu_valor: 0
   },
   methods: {
    somenteNumeros: function (valor) {
      return (valor + '').replace(/\D+/g, '');
    }
   }
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    
<input type="text" @input="meu_valor = somenteNumeros(meu_valor)" v-model="meu_valor">

{{ meu_valor }}
</div>
```